# Use multiple instances (identical code, different config) of a scoped dependency-injected interface

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I have a 3rd party DI library that adds a scoped service. This gives me a pattern something like:

```cs
// in Startup
services.AddScoped<ICustomService>();

// in API
public async Task<ThingResult> DoThing([FromServices] ICustomService service)
{
    return await service.DoThing(...);
}
```

We now need to use this same service again with a different endpoint. OK, so that needs multiple services:

```cs
// in Startup
services.AddScoped<ICustomService>(ukConfig);
services.AddScoped<ICustomService>(usConfig);
services.AddScoped<ICustomService>(auConfig);

// in API
public async Task<ThingResult> DoThing([FromServices] IEnumerable<ICustomService> services)
{
    var juristriction = await this.GetCustomer(...).Juristriction.Key; // UK | US | AU
    var service = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.AppliesTo = juristriction);
    return await service.DoThing(...);
}
```

Is there a better practice here than looping all the services every time?

The `ICustomService` is *scoped*, and it's making HTTP calls so it's creating and closing either an `HttpClient` (hopefully with a factory) or WCF `ClientBase` each time. This could lead to scale/performance issues with lots of scoped requests all initialising lots of scoped services (I think, happy to be corrected if anyone knows for sure?)

OK, so maybe we can use a factory pattern here (like `HttpClient` does):

```cs
// in Startup
services.AddScoped<ICustomServiceFactory>();

// in API
public async Task<ThingResult> DoThing([FromServices] ICustomServiceFactory serviceFactory)
{
    var juristriction = await this.GetCustomer(...).Juristriction.Key; // UK | US | AU
    var config = await this.GetConfig(juristriction);
    var service = serviceFactory.GetService(config );
    return await service.DoThing(...);
}

// IAsyncDisposable for ICustomServiceFactory needs to close all services created during its scoped lifespan
```

But this seems very clunky given .NET's dependency injection is already a big service factory.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: .NET's DI is unfortunately very simplistic. There's no good way to do what you need - only clunky workarounds.

Comment: I agree with @StephenCleary, this might not easy to achieve with MS.DI. Try to make sure that the creation of `ICustomService` instances is fast (by ensuring its constructor doesn't do any I/O nor call any incoming dependency). This allows injecting the complete list of registered `ICustomService` instances and filter them based on their juristriction.

Comment: It looks like a better solution is coming in .NET8 https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/1683956501570879489 I'll update this answer if/when that ships

Answer (score 0):

A factory pattern implementation looks like this:

```cs
#nullable enable
namespace MyProject;

using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>Factory for disposable DI services.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Service type - can't be null and must implement DisposeAsync.</typeparam>
public abstract class ServiceConfigFactory<T>:
    IDisposable,
    IAsyncDisposable 
    where T: notnull, IAsyncDisposable {
    
    /// <summary>Dictionary holding collection of services.</summary>
    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, T> services = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    /// <summary>Create the disposable service, given the config key.
    /// <para>This should throw an exception on failure, rather than null.</para></summary>
    /// <param name="key">The case-insentitive key to find the right configuration.</param>
    /// <returns>The newly created service.</returns>
    protected abstract T Create(string key);

    /// <summary>Get an instance of the service for the given configuration.
    /// <para>If the service already exists return that, if it doesn't then a new one will be created.</para></summary>
    /// <param name="key">The case-insentitive key to find the right configuration.</param>
    /// <returns>Service instance matching the config key.</returns>
    public T Get(string key) =>
        this.services.GetOrAdd(key, this.Create);

#region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        if (this.disposedValue)
            return;

        if(this.services is not null && !this.services.IsEmpty) {
            var keys = this.services.Keys.ToArray();
            var disposals = new List<ValueTask>();
            foreach(var k in keys)
                if(this.services.Remove(k, out T? service))
                    disposals.Add(service.DisposeAsync());

            foreach(var d in disposals)
                await d;

            if(!this.services.IsEmpty)
                foreach(var p in this.services) 
                    await p.Value.DisposeAsync();
        }

        this.disposedValue = true;
    }

    void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (this.disposedValue)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Does the service have a fallback Disposable impl?
            bool isDisposable = typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
            if(isDisposable && 
                this.services is not null && 
                !this.services.IsEmpty) {

                var keys = this.services.Keys.ToArray();
                foreach(var k in keys)
                    if(this.services.Remove(k, out T? service))
                        ((IDisposable)service).Dispose();

                if(!this.services.IsEmpty)
                    foreach(var p in this.services) 
                        ((IDisposable)p.Value).Dispose();
            }
        }

        disposedValue = true;
    }

    ~ServiceConfigFactory() { this.Dispose(false); }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
    {
        await this.DisposeAsyncCore();
#pragma warning disable CA1816 // Dispose methods should call SuppressFinalize
        // Suppress finalization.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
#pragma warning restore CA1816 // Dispose methods should call SuppressFinalize
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then an implementation with this becomes:

```cs
// Service implementation
interface ICustomServiceFactory { ICustomService Get(string key) }

sealed class CustomServiceFactory: 
    ServiceConfigFactory<ICustomService>,
    ICustomServiceFactory {
    protected override ICustomService Create(string key) =>
        new CustomService(GetConfig(key));
}

// in Startup
services.AddScoped<ICustomServiceFactory>();

// in API
public async Task<ThingResult> DoThing([FromServices] ICustomServiceFactory serviceFactory)
{
    var juristriction = await this.GetCustomer(...).Juristriction.Key; // UK | US | AU
    var service = serviceFactory.Get(juristriction);
    return await service.DoThing(...);
}
```

This still feels like reinventing the wheel, I'd love to see a simpler solution.